# WACK check in build

Tags: c#, continuous-integration, win-universal-app, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I have UWP application that I'm working on and also setting up CI for it.
I want to include Windows App Certification Kit (WACK) as a build step to verify all the  builds application against MS rules.

CI is build on the top of Visual Studio Online.
There is an custom Build Agent with the latest software installed attached to my VSO build configuration.
The problem is that WACK requires admin privileges to run, however VSO requires that user that runs BuildAgent should not have admin privileges.

Is there any way to increase privileges of the user during build run?
Is there any workaround to run WACK without admin privileges? 
Even if some of the WACK tests are disabled it still make sense to integrate WACK check into CI.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Reminder that the WACK toolkit is only to be used on RELASE builds with .NET Native enabled. If you run against the DEBUG config build you'll see all sorts of spurious warnings. You may also want to turn in the "Enable static analysis for .NET Native" flag for your CI builds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Admin privilege limitation is only for VSO [Hosted Build Agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/services/hosted-agent-pool), there isn't any way to promote administrator privilege on it. But as soon as you [deploy a custom Build Agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/agents/windows), you will have enough permission to run WACK test.

Note:

Use an account with administrator permission to log on if you are run your build agent as Service.

> If you need to change the logon account, don't do it from the services
>   snap-in. Instead, From an elevated Command Prompt, run:
>   C:\Agent\Agent\VsoAgent.exe /ChangeWindowsServiceAccount

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this approach works! 
In my system I'm using client added as app (not as service). And for me it was enough to just start agent as Admin and this solved the issue - for now WACK runs.